# Turn off email sends from Devise in test (Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Devise 3.5.2
Rails 4.2.5

Email sends are successfully wired up via ActiveJob as defined in instructions [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#activejob-integration). Resque is successfully processing jobs to send emails (using Redis as a data store.)

When Redis is turned off, my RSpec functional tests fail with a `Redis::CannotConnectError`. Ideally, I'd like my functional tests to trigger devise emails, but not deliver anything. I test the `deliveries` array.

---

In `test.rb`, I have:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

Knowing that I'm really using `Devise::Mailer`, I explicitly set the following in `rails_helper`:

```
Devise::Mailer.delivery_method = :test
Devise::Mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

I can confirm these settings (via a `pry` breakpoint) while running my test when I hit the following method in my model.

**Model method:**

```
 def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
   binding.pry
   devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
 end


pry(#<User>)> devise_mailer.perform_deliveries
=> false

pry(#<User>)> devise_mailer.delivery_method
=> :test
```

My test still fails with the `Redis::CannotConnectError` exception.

When I change this line:
`devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later`
to
`devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later unless Rails.env.test?`

my test passes. However, this seems like a bad mixing of test and production code.

What am I missing in my config of the devise mailer to prevent emails being delivered in `RAILS_ENV=test` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When delivery_method is set to test, everything is still run the same, with the only difference being the message is not sent to SMTP.

So, in your case Redis is still required for test emails, as **Resque is still going to process them**, and depends on Redis to queue them.

So your options are to either change your queue method in test, run Redis in test, or do not attempt send in test. From a best practice perspective, you should be sending in test and examining the emails to confirm content, so one or two are going to the best options.

Comment: Could you explain this in a bit more detail ("_change your queue method in test_")?

Comment: See section 4.2 here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html  I would suggest delayed_job as a good alternative, as it can be based on the same database backend as your app, vs. using something different like Resque

Comment: It definitely is respected, but it doesn't take affect until AFTER Resque has processed the email and sent it out for delivery. You aren't telling Rails not to put anything in the queue, you are telling it not to send emails. Sending emails happens after it gets put in the queue.