# How to Skip Devise Confirmation email using SeedFu gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, seeding

I'm using the Seed-Fu gem to populate my database. So, I have this in one of my seed files:

```
User.seed_once(:email) do |user|
  user.id = 1
  user.email = "test@test.com"
  user.first_name = "First"
  user.last_name = "Last"
  user.confirmation_sent_at = Time.zone.now - 1.hour
  user.confirmed_at = Time.zone.now
  user.roles = [root,staff]
  user.permissions = Permission.all
end
```

From what I've read, that *should* prevent Devise from sending a confirmation email. However, it is not, so (since I'm using the Letter Opener gem) my browser is being flooded with confirmation emails. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can convince Devise to not send these emails whilst I'm seeding?

SOLUTION:

Based on anothermh's answer below, I added `Devise::Mailer.perform_deliveries = false` to the top of this fixture file. Then, I found my final fixture file and added `Devise::Mailer.perform_deliveries = true` to the end of that to make sure emails *would* be sent when actually using the app. Thank you so much, folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [turn off email sends from Devise in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876798/turn-off-email-sends-from-devise-in-test-rspec). Specifically, you'll need to have this set somewhere:

```
Devise::Mailer.delivery_method = :test
Devise::Mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

For example, if you're doing this with rspec then you would likely put it into `spec/rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't in the tests. This is in the main fixtures for the application. I use these fixtures to set up the database when I'm working on my local machine.

Comment: That being said, putting just the second line at the top of the fixture file worked! I put the opposite at the end of my final fixture to make sure that emails would be sent when actually using the app. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to call the **confirm** method on user object. See the below code

```
user.confirm
```

So in your case the code will be like

```
User.seed_once(:email) do |user|
  user.id = 1
  user.email = "test@test.com"
  user.first_name = "First"
  user.last_name = "Last"
  user.confirm 
  user.roles = [root,staff]
  user.permissions = Permission.all
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gave me an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'confirm' for #<SeedFu::BlockHash:0x007fa8f0207da8>`. I think it's because the SeedFu gem makes that "user" variable a special kind of object for setting attributes. Thank you, though!